# Trying to extract tabular data from desktop application screen in UI Path

Tags: windows, automation, uipath

I am using UiPath and am currently trying to extract data from a screen that looks like this:
[image: source screen]

When I use the `Screen Scraping` tool, I am able to get the data:
[image: screen scraper result]

But when I add `Get Full Text` activity into my sequence and select the same region, the output to the variable is always blank.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: What is the aim you want to achieve? Not clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the screen scraping tool the scraping method you are using is `native`, Whereas you are using `Get Full Text` activity which is equivalent for`full-text` screen scraping method to retrieve the same in UIPath studio.

So try to use `Get Visible Text` activity (Equivalent to native screen scraping method).

I hope you know there are 3 scraping methods as below

- Full-Text (Equivalent to `Get full text` activity)
- Native (Equivalent to `Get visible text` activity)
- OCR (Equivalent to `Get OCR text` activity)

Please let us know if you have further queries

Comment: `Get Visible Text` also returns a blank